# EF models. Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have my entities like this, they are closely linked.

```
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int FirstTeamId { get; set; }
    public Team FirstTeam { get; set; }
    public int SecondTeamId { get; set; }
    public Team SecondTeam { get; set; }

    public Stadium Stadium { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public GameStatus Result { get; set; }

    public Game(DateTime date , GameStatus result )
    {
        Date = date;
        Result = result;
    }
}

public class Player
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public PlayerStatus Status { get; set; }
    public PlayerHealthStatus HealthStatus { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public Player(string name , string surname, DateTime birthday, PlayerStatus status, PlayerHealthStatus healthStatus, int salary)
    {
        Name = name;
        Surname = surname;
        Birthday = birthday;
        Status = status;
        HealthStatus = healthStatus;
        Salary = salary;
    }

}

public class Stadium
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public int PriceForPlace { get; set; }

    public Stadium(string name, int capacity, int priceForPlace)
    {
        Name = name;
        Capacity = capacity;
        PriceForPlace = priceForPlace;
    }
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Player> Players { get; set; }

    public List<Game> Games { get; set; }

    public Team(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public Team(string name, List<Player> players) : this(name)
    {
        Players = players;

    }
}
```

In my Context class I'm tried to describe my relationships between classes. But something isn't correct.

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Stadium> Stadiums { get; set; }

    public ApplicationContext()
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=best-komp;Database=FootballApplicationDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Player>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Team)
            .WithMany(t => t.Players)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.TeamId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Team>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Players)
            .WithOne(p => p.Team)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.TeamId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
            .HasOne(g => g.FirstTeam)
            .WithMany(t => t.Games)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.FirstTeamId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
            .HasOne(g => g.SecondTeam)
            .WithMany(t => t.Games)
            .HasForeignKey(t => t.SecondTeamId)
            .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id);


    }
}
```

What wrong with this code? Because I have "Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship." error when I try to do something with my ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can't reuse `Team.Games` as the inverse property for both `Game.FirstTeam` and `Team.SecondTeam`. Think of it, if you add game to `Team.Games`, how would EF know which team it is, first or second?

You need two collections to describe the relationships. And that's also a chance to add some more meaning to the class model. For example (only modified code):

```cs
public class Game
{
    ...
    public int HomeTeamId { get; set; }
    public Team HomeTeam { get; set; }
    public int AwayTeamId { get; set; }
    public Team AwayTeam { get; set; }
}

public class Team
{
    ...
    public List<Game> HomeGames { get; set; }
    public List<Game> AwayGames { get; set; }
}
```

For a team it's meaningful to make a distinction between home and away games, for example to compare results in both types of games.

And the mapping:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
    .HasOne(g => g.HomeTeam)
    .WithMany(t => t.HomeGames)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.HomeTeamId)
    .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id);
modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
    .HasOne(g => g.AwayTeam)
    .WithMany(t => t.AwayGames)
    .HasForeignKey(t => t.AwayTeamId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction)
    .HasPrincipalKey(t => t.Id);
```

If using Sql Server, this delete behavior instruction is necessary to prevent disallowed multiple cascade paths.

Comment: maybe u can help with this modelBuilder to all my models, because In some cases I have no reference between models

Comment: Just ask a new question explaining one of those cases.

Comment: Does this mean that both `Game.HomeTeamId` and `Game.AwayTeamId` will be available on the objects extracted and as columns in the DB? But only one will be set, depending on which list it was "added" to in `Team`?

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but I don't agree with the idea that EF couldn't know if a Team is First or Second when adding to `Team.Games`. Every `Game` has `FirstTeamId` and `SecondTeamId` and the configuration clearly says that, for a `Game`, if the foreign key `Game.FirstTeamId`=`Team.Id` add this `Game` reference to the property `Game.FirstTeam`  and the same for the `SecondTeam` (in this case can be `FirstTeam == SecondTeam`, why not). I think this kind of behavior/configuration is now unsupported but not impossible. It's not a undecidable task.

Comment: @JanDrozen Yes, maybe EF could figure this out if it would support this. Since it doesn't, we can't try. But in  most cases, EF allows developers to add objects to collections or to set reference navigation properties without worrying about correct IDs. The idea is that EF figures out the IDs when object graphs are saved. Having to add a Game instance with the correct ID set would violate this principle.

Comment: @GertArnold I agree with you that EF makes the most common case to be usable easily. However, I really dislike situations like this - the EF enforces database architecture changes. In this case it requires two more columns -  HomeTeamId, AwayTeamId - that holds only unnecessary redundant information, which is bad for the database design. If there were a configuration option, it would be great. Something like discriminator property for inheritance. An expression that assigns ref to correct nav collection based on defined rule (translatable to SQL).

Comment: @JanDrozen I don't see how EF demands database design here that could have been more convenient otherwise. My code proposed *renamed* FK fields, no new fields.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your Team model has 2 one-to-many relationships with your Game model but you only have one navigation property on the Team.

You need to have 2 navigation properties on the Team model, one for each relationship.
(Game1, Game2...).

You will also need to define these relationships in the Game model - a Team property for each relationship.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54196199/entity-framework-core-multiple-one-to-many-relationships-between-two-entities) answer for extra info.