# Many to many relationship with the the same table. EF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many, entity-framework-migrations

I have a C# running on .NET 5.0 application. And I have the following tables

```
public class Attribute
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<AssessmentAttributeItem> ItemMappings { get; set; }
    public List<AssessmentAttributeItem> AttributeMappings { get; set; }
    public Attribute()
    {
        ItemMappings = new List<AssessmentAttributeItem>();
        AttributeMappings = new List<AssessmentAttributeItem>();
    }
}

public class AssessmentAttributeItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AttributeId")]
    public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
    
    public int? ItemId { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey("ItemId")]
    public virtual AssessmentItem Item { get; set; }

    public int? ChildAttributeId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChildAttributeId")]
    public virtual Attribute ChildAttribute { get; set; }
}
```

And I am using Fluent API to specify the relationship like the following

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<AssessmentAttributeItem>()
             .HasOne(x => x.Item)
             .WithMany().HasForeignKey(y => y.ItemId);

 modelBuilder.Entity<AssessmentAttributeItem>()
             .HasOne(x => x.Attribute)
             .WithMany(y => y.ItemMappings);

 modelBuilder.Entity<AssessmentAttributeItem>()
             .HasOne(x => x.ChildAttribute)
             .WithMany().HasForeignKey(y => y.ChildAttributeId);
```

Mmy question is: when I try to add migration it is adding an extra column called `AttributeId1`

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
            name: "AttributeId1",
            table: "AssessmentAttributeItems",
            type: "int",
            nullable: true);

public class AssessmentItem
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I want my table to look like this

| ID | AttributeId | ItemId | ChildAttributeId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| . | . | . | . |

Comment: I would like to see Attribute table columns

Comment: @Serge it is the first table in the post

Comment: Thanks, you use AssessmentItem  class too, could  you post it pls?

Comment: I think the problem is I am using AssessmentAttributeItem as a join table for two joins.  Attribute - AssessmentItem
Attribute - (Attribute)ChildAttribute

Comment: Let this serve as a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275324/861716