# Non-static foreign key EF core

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I am working on a messenger API, and it goning be something like discord which someone sends a friend request to another user, and if the user accepted, they start messaging. as you know each `FriendRequest` has two contacts, sender and receiver, there are two ways to implement this relationship, one way is to define a many-to-many relationship between `FriendRequest` and contact and limit the `FriendRequest`'s contacts to two. the other way is to define two properties in `FriendRequest`, `SenderContact` and `ReceiverContact`.

I chose the second way which each `FriendRequest` should have two foreign keys with two contacts. But EF added another foreign key automatically.
I just want to know two things
1: Is the second way that I chose a good way? Is there any better way to implement this situation? 
2: Can I prevent EF from creating the `ContactId` column?

OnModelCreating in MyConext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    builder.Entity<Contact>().HasMany<FriendRequest>().WithOne(f => f.FromContact);
    builder.Entity<Contact>().HasMany<FriendRequest>().WithOne(f => f.ToContact);
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);
}
```

FriendRequest:

```
public class FriendRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Contact FromContact { get; set; }
    public Contact ToContact { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Contact:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Chat> Chats { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FriendRequest> FriendRequests { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Contact> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

[image: My database diagram]

Comment: Your title is not very meaningful. I don't know what you mean by non-static foreign key

Comment: @yousif I think there is no way to say to EF: we always have a foreign key between a contact and a friend request but it's not specified before adding a row; while adding a new friend request we specify that `friendrequest` has a foreign key named `FromContactId` with Contact A (Sender) and another foreign key named `ToContactId` with Contact B (Receiver). this is what I mean by choosing this title.

Comment: To my knowledge, that's not possible. hope you find an answer tho.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59274852/861716

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems okay to me, but you have a configuration error.
Your contact object should be

```
public class Contact
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Chat> Chats { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FriendRequest> SentFriendRequests { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FriendRequest> ReceivedFriendRequests { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Contact> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

FriendRequest can stay the same, tho it is recommended to define a foreign key

```
public class FriendRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Contact FromContact { get; set; }
    public Contact ToContact { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And the configuration

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<Contact>()
          .HasMany<FriendRequest>(c => c.SentFriendRequests)
          .WithOne(f => f.FromContact);

        builder.Entity<Contact>()
          .HasMany<FriendRequest>(c => c.ReceivedFriendRequests)
          .WithOne(f => f.ToContact);

        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
```

I always take a second look at the [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#no-foreign-key-property) when configuring relations, I recommend you do that.

Comment: the problem I had with it was the requests come from clients will be twice and it's not good. Also, a friend request means a request that someone send and someone receive but it is called also a friend request for the receiver. so in my opinion it's better if we use just one property for all friend requests and get them with just one query.